# Is there any way to change the line height of a TextBox in a uwp app?

Tags: xaml, uwp, textbox

Is there any way to change the line spacing or line height of a `TextBox` in a uwp?
wpf:

```
TextBlock.SetLineHeigh(textboxName, 30)
```

but  uwp  is not  allow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to change the line spacing or line height of a TextBox in a uwp?

UWP TextBox does not support set line height. Please use [`RichEditBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RichEditBox) to replace.

Derive from rob's [reply](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/010dee54-f8e7-41c6-9c0f-beecb95fa084/how-to-set-the-line-spacing-of-richeditbox?forum=winappswithcsharp),

> `RichEditBox`can represent rich text. The RichEditBox's underlying engine is more similar to the one in WordPad.
>
> You can change the formatting in the `RichEditBox` by manipulating properties on the [`Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.document.aspx). You can set the line spacing by getting an [`ITextRange's ParagraphFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextrange.paragraphformat.aspx) and [`callingITextParagraphFormat.SetLineSpacing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextparagraphformat.setlinespacing.aspx) method.